# magit status buffer disappears

Tags: magit, buffers

Magit status used to create a buffer with the buffer name `magit: repo name`.  I recently upgraded Spacemacs and the Magit status buffer started to disappear whenever its window was not visible, and it doesn't show up in my buffer list.

I can keep it by renaming the buffer, but that's pretty annoying.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Same issue here. Has anyone found a way to keep the magit-status buffer? I started having this issue after migrating to Spacemacs

Comment: Does it happen from `emacs -Q`? If not, maybe it's worth report it to Spacemacs.

Comment: Just to be sure; which buffer list? The list shown by `SPC b b`, or the actual buffer list (printed with `M-: (buffer-list)`)? Could you try to first do `M-: (setq magit-buffer (current-buffer))` in the magit-status buffer and then, without killing the magit-status buffer, but making it non-visible, do `M-: (memq magit-buffer (buffer-list))` from another buffer. If the magit-status buffer really gets killed, then open an issue at [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) (although I can not reproduce the behavior here).